# chaining operator throwing error in express app

Tags: javascript, express, operator-overloading

I am trying to use the optional chaining operator (?.) in my express app - it throws error whenever i try.

```
if (user.address?.postal_code.length > 0 ) {
                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
```

I have tried all variations

```
user?.address?.postal_code?.length
user?.address?.postal_code.length
user?.address.postal_code.length


"engines": {
        "node": "10.16.0",
        "npm": "6.9.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Upgrade your Node version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options

1. Upgrade your Node version. Only [these](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----) versions support optional chaining. As you can see, only Node 14.5+ supports optional chaining
2. If you want to support older versions such as 12, you will need to transpile your code. Take a look at [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). These programs take your code and transform it into code that is compatible with older Node versions. For example, your code:

```js
if (user.address?.postal_code.length > 0 ) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Turns into:

```js
var _user$address;

if (((_user$address = user.address) === null || _user$address === void 0 ? void 0 : _user$address.postal_code.length) > 0) {
    // Do stuff
}
```